# Can not log into mssql-server on Fedora 35 after install

Tags: sql-server, fedora

I have followed these [instructions](https://kifarunix.com/install-microsoft-sql-server-2017-on-fedora-29-centos-7/) to install mssql-server on Fedora 35. But I cannot log in!
Status:

```
mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mssql-server.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-07 10:30:34 EST; 9min ago
```

I have tried to find a password that is accepted by mssql-server and bash friendly.
Special character just enable a new line in bash. I have tried escaping the special character with '' with no success.

I am still getting the `Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8`. Sometimes it is the State 7 error.

What is the fix? Does anyone have a suggested password that works with mssql-server and bash?

Comment: Standard caveat that SQL Server on Linux is not supported of Fedora, so if it's not working properly, it could simply be a result of you using it on an unsupported environment.

Comment: Also, you would have been asked for the password for the `sa` account when you created the instance; did you not take a mental or physical note of what that was?

Comment: I have Sql Server 2017 installed on Fedora 35 and used a password similar to Pass%word1972 and it works. Same is true for Sql Server 2019 on Fedora 34. The special characters '!',  '$'  and '^' do strange things when entered into the bash command line.

Answer (score 0):

Success!
By changing the special character to '%' works.
At the bash promt:

```
>echo Password%4398
>Password%4398
```

Then used:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
```

Now the password is accepted by mssql-server.